# How to stop Visio 2007 toolbars from rearranging when I open ShapeSheet?

Tags: microsoft-visio, toolbar, microsoft-visio-2007

(With *edits italicized*)
I normally run with one VSD open, maximized within the Visio 2007 window.  I have a mix of custom and standard toolbars, all moved onto one row:

[image]

*Note that I have lots of buttons, so most of the time not all of them are visible because my Visio window is too narrow.*

However, about a third of the time, when I right-click on a shape and open the ShapeSheet *and then click back to the drawing window with the ShapeSheet window still open*, the toolbars expand to full width and stagger themselves across multiple rows:

[image]

How can I stop that from happening?

**Environment:** Visio 2007 SP3 32-bit running on Win 8.1 Enterprise 64-bit.  Behaviour is not 100% consistent, but does happen in multiple VSD files.

**Edit**: If I leave the ShapeSheet open, click back to the document, and rearrange the fixed toolbars, it sticks for a little while while I try opening and closing the file, and exiting and restarting Visio.  It then eventually goes back to staggering.

I ran one test in which I (starting with Visio not running):

1. Opened a file by double-clicking it in Explorer;
2. Right-clicked on the group that is the only top-level shape on the sheet and selected ShapeSheet;
3. Clicked back to the document MDI window in Visio to see how the toolbars were arranged;
4. Exited Visio by clicking the close box on the title bar; and
5. Repeated the above about ten times for the same Visio file.

During the test, the toolbars periodically rearranged themselves, sometimes staggered and sometimes in other arrangements.

I ran the test above both windowed (window too narrow for all buttons) and maximized (window definitely wide enough for all buttons) and saw the same results: sometimes the toolbars come back in a different place than where I left them.

Answer (score 2):

You can't stop them from rearranging. In fact they are not being rearranged, Visio changes the toolbars that are visible when the shapesheet editor is opened. However, the 2 layouts can be controlled independently, so just rearrange the toolbars as you want to see them while the shapesheet editor is open.

Comment: Paul, thanks!  I tried that but am still experiencing rearrangment without a discernable pattern.  Please see edited question --- any thoughts?